# Splitting R dataframe doesn't preserve row names

Tags: r, slice

I am trying to split a dataframe into rolling chunks, stored in a list, for cross validation.

Here's is my code:

```
split_data <- function(data, window.size) {
  windows.count = NROW(data) - window.size
  res = vector(mode="character", windows.count)
  print(head(data)) # (1)

  for(d in 0:windows.count) {
    res[d+1] <- data[(1+d):(window.size + d),,drop=FALSE]
    print(head(res[[d+1]])) # (2)
  }

  return(res)
}
```

If I look at what was logged out at (1) I can clearly see the row names are in my data. After executing the slice and storing it at `res[d+1]` (2) indicates there are no longer row names in the associated dataframe.

Row names are very important for my cross validation. Is there anyway I can use them here? The answer always seems to be to add `drop=FALSE` to  the slicing operation but here that doesn't work.

Thank you!

EDIT:

To recreate a dataset to try this on:

```
label <- c("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6")
dat <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
dats <- data.frame(dat)
rownames(dats) <- label
```

Run the function `split_data(dats, 2)`

The desired output is a list of dataframes:

```
       dats
test1     1
test2     2

       dats
test2     2  
test3     3

       dats
test3     3
test4     4

       dats
test4     4
test5     5

       dats
test5     5
test6     6
```

I'd put the actual list output but I can't get it to generate. This should give a good enough indication of what should be inside the list for each element of the list.

Comment: Please provide a starting dataset and a desired output.

Comment: @Abdou Gave the best indication of what I want as output and an example dataset. Additionally I edited it to mean row names not column names.

Comment: Also `lapply(1:(nrow(dats)-wind+1), function(x) dats[x:(x+wind-1),,drop=FALSE] )` if you want to avoid all the pre-allocation and loop code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change from mode="character" to "list". You are trying to store data.frames in character vector though in order for your approach you would need a list.

In addition, modify res[d+1] to be res[[d+1]]. Given that res is now a list res[d+1] returns a list where's res[[d+1]] returns the data.frame contained inside of it. This has a pretty good overview of the difference: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Here is your modified function and example:

```
split_data <- function(data, window.size) {
  windows.count = NROW(data) - window.size
  res = vector(mode="list", windows.count)

  for(d in 0:windows.count) {
    res[[d+1]] <- data[(1+d):(window.size + d),,drop=FALSE]
  }

  return(res)
} 

label <- c("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6")
dat <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
dats <- data.frame(dat)
rownames(dats) <- label

split_data(dats,  2)

split_data(mtcars, 10) # example with mtcars dataset
```

Similar to what was said in the comments, this is one way I would do this:

```
split_data2 <- function(data, window.size) {
  lapply(0:(nrow(dats) - window.size), 
         function(i) dats[(1 + i):(window.size + i), , drop = F])
}

split_data2(dats, 2)
```

Comment: Why does this work? Could you update your answer with that?

Comment: Updated, hopefully that helps